# No puedo actualizar una app instaladia vía APK

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

Instalé mi aplicación (Singed APK) en varios dispositivos, ahora he publicado dicha aplicación con más de un cambio (he puesto un numero de versionCode y versionName superior al que había en esos apk). El caso es que ahora voy a la playStore y no me deja actualizarlo, solo desinstalar y abrir.

Comment: la instalaste desde playstore o la instalaste a partir del apk?

Comment: Desde el apk Pablo

Comment: Si la instalaste desde el apk no te va a dejar actualizar. Para que te deje hacer eso tienes que instalarla desde Play store y cuando subas una nueva versión será cuando te de la opción de actualizar. –

Comment: Jose, estas seguro de tener el mismo packagename? veo que marcaste una respuesta como correcta, pero cual es el punto de esa respuesta que consideras correcto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es posible instalar el APK manualmente para actualizar pero:

1. El nombre de Paquete antiguo debe ser el mismo que el de la versión actual.
2. Se debe generar la APK firmada con la opción "Generate Signed APK" no con la opción "Build APKs"
3. Debe ser firmada con la misma Keystore de la versión anterior, para verificar si estás usando la misma firma que la versión anterior, puedes correr el siguiente comando con las versiones antigua y nueva, si el resultado es el mismo, significa que ambas APKs están usando la misma firma.

   ```
   $ jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs my_application.apk
   ```
4. Debe tener un código de versión (versionCode) superior a la versión anterior, por ejemplo, si antes era 4, ahora debe ser 5 o superior.

Si cumples con todo lo anterior podrás actualizar tu aplicación tanto instalando de forma manual como instalando desde Google Play.

Si deseas más información de como actualizar tu aplicación, te invito a visitar ésta página, son los pasos oficiales en inglés.

[Update your apps](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

Si la instalaste desde el apk no te va a dejar actualizar. Para que te deje hacer eso tienes que instalarla desde Play store y cuando subas una nueva versión será cuando te de la opción de actualizar. –

Comment: Actualmente **un .APK  instalado que no proviene de la tienda ya puede permitir actualizaciones**, simplemente necesita un versionCode mayor.

Answer (score 0):

Actualmente puedes generar un .apk y actualizar desde Google Playstore si es que existe una nueva versión de la aplicación.

Para que pueda considerarse una actualización de la aplicación:

> - Debes tener el mismo `package name`, que en realidad es el id de la aplicación, si tiene uno diferente al de la versión instalada se
>     considerara como otra aplicación.
> - La aplicación que se considerará para actualización debe tener definido un [versionCode](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html) mayor.

Definir el [versionCode](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html) dentro del archivo `build.gradle` sobre escribe la configuración del `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
android {
  defaultConfig { 
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.1"
  }
  ...
  ...
}
```